# How to limit UILabel to 25 characters and show dots if exceeds using auto layout

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel, ios-autolayout

I want to restrict UILabel text to 25 characters and if text length exceeds I need to show dots at end(...).I gave constraints to UILabel in storyboard.

To restrict I used below code:

```
 if (cell.lblSubHeadingTop.text?.characters.count)! >= 25 {

        cell.lblSubHeadingTop.text = cell.lblSubHeadingTop.text?.substring(with: 0..<25)

    }

   cell.lblSubHeadingTop.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    cell.lblSubHeadingTop.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
```

limit is working fine but how to show dots if length exceeds?

Any help to solve this issue.

Comment: from storyboard just select linebreakmode truncate trail option in attribute inspector for label

Comment: Limit the label size to accommodate 25 characters. Label will truncate it if it exceeds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like,

```
  if (lbl.text?.characters.count)! >= 25 {

        let index = lbl.text?.index((lbl.text?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: 25)
        lbl.text = lbl.text?.substring(to: index!)
        lbl.text = lbl.text?.appending("...")
    }

    //lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    //lbl.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
```

And your `constraints` should be like : `Top,leading,fixed height`!